# Good free resources for learning set theory

Tags: set-theory

I'm looking to learn set theory.  My coding history has been primarily practical and I'd like to move more into the theory side of things.  I think I understand the basic concepts of set theory but I know nothing about its applications, its notations, and operations you can perform on sets.

Any resources that could point me in the right direction would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Set as a Data Structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(computer_science))

General theory

1. [Set Theory for Computer Science](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~gwinskel/STiCS.pdf)
2. [What practical applications does set theory have?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10334/what-practical-applications-does-set-theory-have)

Comment: @Max updated the link for (1)